# Function is not called because of ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this:

```
<div class="row"
     ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'| filter:{ paid: '0' } ">        
    <div class="col left">
        <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="processed" id="processed"
               ng-true-value="'1'"
               ng-false-value="'0'"
               ng-model="x.processed"
               ng-click="changeProcessedStatus(x.id, x.processed)">上菜/未上菜
        <P>
    </div>
    <div class="col left">
        <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="paid" id="paid"
               ng-true-value="'1'"
               ng-false-value="'0'"
               ng-model="x.paid"
               ng-click="changePaidStatus(x.id, x.paid)">付款/未付款
        <P>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click checkbox "processed", it works fine (changeProcessedStatus function is called). But when I click checkbox "paid", since the record is defined to be filtered, changePaidStatus function is not called.(I don't know why) when I remove ng-repeat filter, changePaidStatus function is called normally.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: When you click on the checkbox, is the element removed from your list correctly, without making a call to your function?

Comment: Just a guess: if you replace your `ng-click=""` by a `ng-change=""`, does it work?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, thanks for your concerns. Firstly "paid"'s value is '0', the record can be seen. When i click checkbox "paid", I want to call changePaidStatus to update database, at same time, "paid"'s value become '1', the record should be filtered.

Comment: Thank you! @DeblatonJean-Philippe! ng-change works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of execution of ng-click and ng-model is ambiguous. Instead you should use ng-change to ensure that you obtain the correct values of the model variable:

```
<div class="row"
 ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'| filter:{ paid: '0' } ">        
    <div class="col left">
        <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="processed" id="processed"
               ng-true-value="'1'"
               ng-false-value="'0'"
               ng-model="x.processed"
               ng-change="changeProcessedStatus(x.id, x.processed)">上菜/未上菜
        <P>
    </div>
    <div class="col left">
        <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="paid" id="paid"
               ng-true-value="'1'"
               ng-false-value="'0'"
               ng-model="x.paid"
               ng-change="changePaidStatus(x.id, x.paid)">付款/未付款
        <P>
    </div>
</div>
```